# Azure Data Factory - two identical pipelines do not behave identically

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Please, help me diagnose the bug or a misconfiguration

I have 2 identical Azure Data Factories **testA_ADF** and **testB_ADF** (one is a copy of another, with name changed.
They reside in the identical resource groups **testA_rg** and **testB_rg**
Pipeline takes a parameter ***pPL_paramId*** of type string - so the parameter is named the same in both pipelines.

I am running the following invocation

```
$id='value'
$parameters = @{
    "pPL_paramId" = "$id"
}
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName 'testA_rg' -DataFactoryName 
'testA_ADF' -PipelineName 'PL_tesPipeline' -Parameter $parameters
    
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName 'testB_rg' -DataFactoryName 
'testB_ADF' -PipelineName 'PL_tesPipeline' -Parameter $parameters
```

I can run both invoikes together like shown, and appart - one by one, and getting the strange behavior, that I can't understand.
Pipeline '***PL_tesPipeline***' works just fine when called from `testA_rg/testA_ADF`
But in the `testB_rg/testB_ADF` the parameter '**pPL_paramId**' is coming as NULL when entering the pipeline execution.
The pipelines, the datafactory and resource groups are the same except for their names, when compared as json code files.

Where should I look to check what can go wrong with the configurations?

Comment: Do both pipelines work when manually executed inside the data factory UI? As an experiment, try resetting the id and parameters values before the second call.

Comment: Yes, they do.
I am sorry, I meant to include that int he OP

Comment: It is not resetting of id that matters ... I do call them together, and apart - separately from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter will take a `null` value only when you don't pass any value to that parameter from the explicit call.

Here, for example, I am passing the value with the wrong parameter name from PowerShell.

```
$id='value'
$parameters = @{
    "wrong_par_name" = "$id"
}
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName '<Resource_group_name>' -DataFactoryName 'Datafactory_name' -PipelineName '<pipeline_name>' -Parameter $parameters
```

[image]

You can see that it took the original parameter `pPL_paramId` value as `null`.

[image]

The pipeline run when I have given the correct parameter name.

[image]

So, recheck the parameter name that you are passing to your second pipeline and make sure the names are the same.